# Navigation Architecture Component - popBackStack without removing Fragment from BackStack

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I want to implement BottomNavigation using Navigation Architecture Component. Everything works fine, except after changing items, fragments don't save theirs state. What I have done was to override onNavigationSelectedListener from BottonNavigationView, and popBackStack when fragment was added to it:

```
setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    if (!navigation.popBackStack(it.itemId, false))
        navigation.navigate(it.itemId)
    true
}
```

It works fine but only for the first pooping of Back Stack, after it the fragment is removed from it, and cannot be pooped when the navigation occurs.

My question is if there is any possibility to Pop Back Stack and not remove fragment from it, using only Android Architecture Component